# ¿Como crear una carpeta con todos los permisos 777 pero en Windows?

Tags: php, linux, windows, permisos

Alguien sabe como crear o cambiarles los permisos a una carpeta para que sean parecidos a 777 como linux, pero en windows

Es para un proyecto en php, pero no me deja subir archivos por que la carpeta no tiene los permisos de recibirlos.

como le hago?, esto es parte del codigo

```
    $valimg = getimagesize($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name']);
    $size = $_FILES['thumb']['size'];//15000=150kb
    $carpeta = "img/";
    $destino = $carpeta .$thumb;   
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777);
}
    if ($valimg != false) {
        if ($size <= 15000) {
            $archivo_subido = $_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($archivo_subido, $carpeta . $thumb );

            ?>
            <script>
                alert('Producto creado exitosamente');
            </script>
            <?php  
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error en concreto que te arroja PHP? Porque si eres admin de la sesion puedes trabajar sin problema.

Comment: @EdgarGc no me arroja un error, solo que no los sube

Comment: Tiene que arrojarte un error o, lo mas lógico, la condicional no esta dando `true`. Deberías comprobar el valor de `$valimg` y `$size`

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar los permisos de un dictorio en windows, sería:

```
 icacls C:\directorio /grant Everyone:F /t
```

Aquí le estamos dando permiso a todos sobre el directorio "directorio"